# Unexpected Error: Reassignment to val

Tags: scala

I get this error when compiling:

```
Compilation error: reassignment to val
```

I think this seems obvious, but when looking at my code I can't find why this doesn't works.

Here is the sample of code where the error happens, from my ConferenceController.scala:

```
def createConfWithPrivacy(confId: Long, groupId: Option[Long]) = ForcedAuthentication 
{implicit request =>
    Future {
      val user = request.user.get
      var newConf = Conference.findById(confId).get
      if(groupId.isDefined){
        newConf.forGroup = LabGroup.findById(groupId.get)  <- there it is
        Conference.updateForGroup(newConf)
      }
      ...
    }
}
```

The variables in Conference.scala are declared like following:

```
case class Conference (
    id         : Long,
    title      : String,
    abstr      : String,
    speaker    : Speaker,
    startDate  : DateTime,
    length     : Duration,
    organizedBy: Lab,
    location   : Location,
    accepted   : Boolean,
    acceptCode : Option[String],
    priv       : Boolean,
    forGroup   : Option[LabGroup]=None
) {... Functions ...}
```

The functions called is from the LabGroup.scala file, I know this one works:

```
def findById(id: Long): Option[LabGroup] = DB.withConnection { implicit  c =>
    SQL("SELECT * FROM LabGroup WHERE id = {id}")
      .on("id" -> id)
      .as(labGroupParser.singleOpt)
  }
```

But I don't understand why this error happens because newConf is a var and normally the Conference.forGroup should be one too.

If you see something done wrong, please tell me.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you instantiate a case class like you have done, every member of it is a **val** by default. You have to explicitly tell Scala that you want to have it as a **var**. Just do it like that:

```
case class Conference (
    id         : Long,
    ...
    var forGroup   : Option[LabGroup]=None
)
```

**EDIT:**
As [Régis Jean-Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1632462/r%C3%A9gis-jean-gilles) posted in his comment, a more idiomatic way of changing the value of **forGroup** would be this code:

> newConf.forGroup = newConf.copy(forGroup = LabGroup.findById(groupId.get))

This would leave forGroup as a **Value** and is a better [functional] way of doing "reassignments".

Comment: You can also just use `copy`: `newConf = newConf .copy(forGroup = LabGroup.findById(groupId.get))`. That's arguably better, and more idiomatic (but in the end only OP can tell what's best for him/her).

Comment: It works well thanks a lot.
Régis your solution is nice too and do the job as well, I'll take it to let the conference as-is.

Answer (score 5):

`var newConf = Conference.findById(confId).get` defines a variable `newConf`. This variable can be reassigned. However, the `forGroup` **value** of `newConf` is still just that, a value, and as such it cannot be changed.

If you want to update `forGroup` for `newConf`, then it needs to be declared variable, which you can do with :

```
case class Conference (
    id         : Long,
    // ...
    var forGroup   : Option[LabGroup]=None
)
```