# Scala: Validating Restful Parameters in Controller

Tags: rest, validation, playframework, mutability

I'm trying to validate a language parameter coming in from a RESTful API. I want to change en_US to en-US, but the parameters coming in are defined as val.

I understand that val types can't be reassigned, but then how do we validate parameters. Here's my controller code.

```
def create = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit rs =>
    var feedback = rs.body.validate[FeedbacksView]
    feedback.fold(
      errors => {
        play.api.Logger.debug(JsError.toJson(errors).toString())
        Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> JsError.toJson(errors))))
      },
      feedbackView => {
        feedbackService.createUpdate(feedbackView,"quality_feedback_created").map { result =>
          val updatedFeedbackView = result.feedbacks.headOption.get.copy(id = Some(result.feedbacks.headOption.get.id.get))
          Ok(Json.toJson(updatedFeedbackView))
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

And here's my FeedbacksView case class.

```
case class FeedbacksView(feedbacks: Seq[FeedbackView] = Seq.empty) {

}
```

And here's my FeedbackView case class.

```
case class FeedbackView(id: Option[UUID] = None,
                        targetLanguage: String,
                        feedbackNotes: Option[String] = None
                       ) {
  targetLanguage = targetLanguage.replace("_", "-"); // Val reassignment error
```

How do I make targetLanguage mutable?

Answer (score 0):

After adjusting my Google search query, I found the answer. In Scala, you must explicitly describe a RESTful API parameter as "var" in the controller. Here's the stack overflow post I found.

[Unexpected Error: Reassignment to val](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596854/unexpected-error-reassignment-to-val)